# Iterative Search in repository (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have this dynamic permission based feature I am trying to implement with spring boot whereby for every action a user wants to take, I want to query the database to know if that user has such authority or permission by checking his role, but a user can have multiple roles, now the problem is how do I perform an iterative search on a set of roles in my repository ???
My permission repository

```
@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, Long>{
Permission findByRoleAndEntitiesAndOperations(Set<Role> role, Entities entities, Operations operations);
}
```

My Role class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleId;
    
    private String name;
       
}
```

My Permission Class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Permission implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long permission_id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    private Entities entities;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id")
    private Operations operations;
    
}
```

My Entities Class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Entities implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long entity_id;
    
    private String entity;
}
```

My Operations class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Operations implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long operation_id;
    
    private String name;
}
```

So i have manually set some default roles, entities, operations, permissions
and persisted them on startup using CommandLineRunner interface

For example, this is my DefaultEntities Class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DefaultEntities {
    
    private final String [] entities = {"Users","Role","Permission","Beat","Genre"};   
    
}
```

This my DefaultRoles class

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DefaultRoles {
    
    public static final String DEFAULT_ROLE = "ROLE_USER";
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    public static final String ROLE_MODERATOR = "ROLE_MODERATOR";
    
}
```

This is my DefaultOperations class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DefaultOperations {
    
    private final String [] operations = {"CREATE","READ","UPDATE","DELETE"};      
}
```

And i have created startup classes to persist the data in all default classes to their various tables example the startup class for adminpermission looks like this

```
@Component
@Order(5)
public class AdminPermissionAddition implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    PermissionRepository permissionRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    OperationsRepository operationsRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;
    
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        Role rol = roleRepository.findByName(DefaultRoles.ROLE_ADMIN);
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(rol);
        List<Operations> operations = operationsRepository.findAll();
        List<Entities> entities = entityRepository.findAll();
        
        roles.forEach((role) -> {
            entities.forEach((entity) -> {
                operations.stream().map((operation) -> {
                    Permission permission = new Permission();
                    permission.setEntities(entity);
                    permission.setOperations(operation);
                    return permission;
                }).map((permission) -> {
                    permission.setRole(role);
                    return permission;
                }).forEachOrdered((permission) -> {
                    permissionRepository.save(permission);
                });
            });
        });
    }    
}
```

So i am having this user with more than one role, and i want my permission repository to search in the set of roles that user has and return a true or false if any of the roles of that user with a given operation and given entity is in the permission table, the permission repository is above...
Please if you think there are any better ways to achieving this, please share with me, i would appreciate
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please give more context. For example the Permission entity.

Comment: @TamásPollák i have updated it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update. So the most important part of your question: *i want my permission repository to search in the **set of roles that user has** and return a true or false if any of the roles of that user with **a given operation** and **given entity** is in the permission table*

Your initial repository query is almost good. It should look something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, Long>{
    Permission findByRoleInAndEntitiesAndOperations(Set<Role> role, Entities entities, Operations operations);
}
```

The important part is that you have to change findByRole to -> findByRole**In** (because you check against a collection)

There is a chance that this query will not work, because comparing entities, but you get the basic idea now. An alternative can be to compare the ids:

```
@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, Long>{
    Permission findByRole_roleIdInAndEntities_Entities_idAndOperations_Operation_id(Set<Long> roleIds, long entityId, long operationId);
}
```

Edit: you can use `boolean existsBy..` instead of `Permission findBy..`. This way you can easily check the boolean result. If it's true, the permission exists, if false then the user does not have the permission for the operation.